# How handoff work between iOS devices?

Tags: ios8

I have built a app, and create a NSUserActiviy obj just like in the SDK document.

I call becomeCurrent after created and needSave after something changed.

I was using an iPhone & two iPad, logged to the same iCloud ID.

But Nothing happen like in the WWDC video(a small icon in the bottom-left in the lock screen).

I have tried using person-hotspot, still not working.

anyone know what i missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you [Specifying an Activity Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/AdoptingHandoff/AdoptingHandoff.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014338-CH2-SW5)?

You need to add an array in you Info.plist with the key `NSUserActivityTypes`, this array must contains all the activity types that you app supports, like `com.myCompany.myBrowser.browsing`.

You also need to enable the bluetooth in both devices.

Comment: At that time, I was working with beta 1 or 2, handoff was just disabled, now is good. thanks anyway